# Running code only once in an OCaml library

Tags: c, ocaml, native-methods

I am writing an OCaml library that has some initialization code that needs to be run only once during the lifetime of the program using the library (and store some state that will persist for the lifetime of the program, but only be used within the library itself), and some cleanup code that needs to be run only as the program using the library exits.

If it is relevant, my library is two parts: an interface to a low-level C library, and some higher-level stuff to make programming with it easier. Can I do what I need somewhere in the C? Ideally my users wouldn't care *how* it was implemented, they would never see the C bits.

In Python I would do this by running code on `import` but OCaml's `open` doesn't actually run anything, it just sugars the module namespace, and then Python's `atexit`, but I can't find the Ocaml equivalent.

One approach I have considered is structuring my library as a "framework" but I don't think it's important enough to warrant such an over-engineered approach. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: OK got it - I think. I am using the C code to handle the cleanup on exit and I have monkeyed with the code a bit so there is a pointer to the global state on the C side

It would *appear* that in my library I now have

```
let global_env = env_create ()
```

And when it is `open`'d by the main program, this *does* get run... But how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that this can be done on the OCaml side with [`Pervasives.at_exit`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VALat_exit) and top-level statements to create the environment and install the cleanup code :

```
let env = init ()
let cleanup () = do_clean env
let () = at_exit cleanup 

let f x = f_stub env x
```

The toplevel statements are executed when the module is loaded (whether you eventually use it or not) and modules are loaded in the order you specified them at link time (thus modules depending on others are guaranteed that their dependencies are initialized when their turn comes), see "Arguments ending with .cmo" in the [manual of ocamlc](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual022.html#toc85). This entails that toplevel statements will have executed before you try to access the module. It's not a matter of opening the module, `open` is just a (bad) syntactic convenience.

If you want the init code to be performed if and only if a function of the module eventually gets called use a lazy value :

```
let env = lazy (init ())
let cleanup () = if Lazy.lazy_is_val env then (do_clean env) else () 
let () = at_exit cleanup

let f x = f_stub (Lazy.force env) x
```

Btw. don't forget to document the resulting issues with thread-safety...

Answer (score 1):

Just as `let x = function ...` defines a function `x` that is available from that point 
onwards, your `let global_env = ...` defines a value `global_env` that is. If you don't 
need the return value of `env_create`, because you run it only for it's side effects, 
you could also just mention `env_create ()` at the end (to be honest, anywhere) of the 
ml file. 
In this case I would do `let _ = env_create ()` though, which I think is more explicit.

**EDIT**: R pointed out that the following is wrong: 
"To do it purely in C, I think that `_init` and `_fini` are the things to look for." 
As explained in this [HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/miscellaneous.html), it is indeed deprecated and should now be done via attributes.

Comment: The second paragraph is definitely wrong. That's not pure C, it's clashing with and redefining functions internal to the implementation, and completely bogus. It will break linking with C++ libraries and lots of other stuff.

Comment: So `open` *does* run code in the module? I thought it was just moving things into your current namespace?

Comment: @R. Logically, you are wrong, I thought that that was the way to do it ;-) ... but it seems not any more. I've edited. thank's for pointing it out.

Comment: @Gaius, no `open` does not evaluate anything. but, to be able to open the module has also to be loaded, via #load or #use in the toplevel, or by linking in compiled code. This is when the code is run. So even if you do not open the module and thus use `MyCWrapperModule.whatever` the code will get executed.